# SDL2 on Raspberry Pi 4: SDL Initialization failed No available video device

Tags: raspberry-pi, sdl, sdl-2, sdl-image

I was having a problem getting one of my programs that uses SDL to compile so to fix it I reinstalled SDL2 and SDL2Image following this link:
https://solarianprogrammer.com/2015/01/22/raspberry-pi-raspbian-getting-started-sdl-2/
I used this link before and have created windows and renderers successfully.
Now the program compiles and runs but I get the error

```
SDL Initialization failed no available video device
```

When initializing SDL.

I am not sure what video system is being used because the configuration command disables mir wayland x11 and opengl.  The tutorial says something about forcing opengl es.

FOR SDL2:

I downloaded and unpacked the tar file into my home directory, then configured using this command:

```
../configure --disable-pulseaudio --disable-esd --disable-video-mir --disable-video-wayland --disable-video-x11 --disable-video-opengl
```

The output was:

```
SDL2 Configure Summary:
Building Shared Libraries
Building Static Libraries
Enabled modules : atomic audio video render events joystick haptic power filesystem threads timers file loadso cpuinfo assembly
Assembly Math   :
Audio drivers   : disk dummy oss alsa(dynamic) sndio
Video drivers   : dummy opengl_es1 opengl_es2
Input drivers   : linuxev linuxkd
Using libudev   : YES
Using dbus      : YES
```

I then used: make -j 4

then: sudo make install

FOR SDL2_Image:

I configured with: ../configure, there was no summary

then: make -j 4

then: sudo make install

I just tried the test program that the tutorial link gives and it executes and displays the image properly, here is the code for initializing things:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     // Initialize SDL
     check_error_sdl(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0, "Unable to initialize SDL");
 
     // Create and initialize a 800x600 window
     SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test SDL 2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                           800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
     check_error_sdl(window == nullptr, "Unable to create window");
 
     // Create and initialize a hardware accelerated renderer that will be refreshed in sync with your monitor (at approx. 60 Hz)
     SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
     check_error_sdl(renderer == nullptr, "Unable to create a renderer");
 
     // Set the default renderer color to corn blue
     SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 100, 149, 237, 255);
 
     // Initialize SDL_img
     int flags=IMG_INIT_JPG | IMG_INIT_PNG;
     int initted = IMG_Init(flags);
     check_error_sdl_img((initted & flags) != flags, "Unable to initialize SDL_image");
```

I copied that code over exactly to my code and I no longer get the SDL Init. failed but I get these errors:

```
Unable to initialize SDL_image Invalid renderer
Unable to create texture Invalid renderer
Unable to create texture Invalid renderer
Unable to create texture Invalid renderer
```

It is a 1-to-1 copy of this test file so I'm not sure what could be going on.  Any suggesstions?

UPDATE:

After recompiling the test program it no longer works either and gives the SDL Init failed error.  I compiled with this line:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic sdl2_test.cpp -o sdl2_test `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2_image
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reconfigured and installed, instead of configuring with:

```
../configure --disable-pulseaudio --disable-esd --disable-video-mir --disable-video-wayland --disable-video-x11 --disable-video-opengl
```

I simply did:

```
../configure
```

Not sure if this will introduce other problems down the road but for now the images display and keyboard input can be captured.